# I'm trying to read a simple Json file but im getting saved a null. What am i doing wrong? My json contains only 4 fields

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

Im trying to write a micrservice to read json using jackson mapper by using below code

```
      @Bean
    CommandLineRunner runner(ResponseService responseService) {
        return args -> {
            // read JSON and load json
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            TypeReference<List<Response>> typeReference1 = new TypeReference<List<Response>>() {};
            InputStream inputStream1 = TypeReference.class.getResourceAsStream("/json/response.json");
            try {
                List<Response> responses = mapper.readValue(inputStream1, typeReference1);
                responseService.save(responses);
                System.out.println(responses);
                System.out.println("response saved");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("not saved" + e.getMessage());
            }

        };
    }

    @Service
public class ResponseService {
    private ResponseRepository responseRepository;

    public ResponseService(ResponseRepository responseRepository) {
        this.responseRepository = responseRepository;
    }

    public Iterable<Response> list() { return responseRepository.findAll();
    }

    public void save(List<Response> users) {
        responseRepository.saveAll(users);
    }
}
```

Comment: Its hard to answer from the provided class references. you can check these: First: `"/json/response.json"` is this file path okay? 
second: `responseService.save(responses);
                System.out.println(responses);` does this output responses?

Comment: 1. i think so this is my path - C:\Users\Desktop\spring-boot-jsontodb-master\src\main\resources\json - response.json

Comment: 2. yes im getting response as null

Comment: [
  {
    "LOGADDR": "1000002624",
    "CATEGORY": "ADD",
    "NAME": "POLYTEC COMPOSITES GERMANY",
    "STATUS": "ACTI"
  },
  {
    "LOGADDR": "1000002625",
    "CATEGORY": "ADD",
    "NAME": "POLYTEC COMPOSITES GERMANY",
    "STATUS": "ACTI"
  }
]

Answer (score 0):

As you stated in comment your path is:

```
C:\Users\Desktop\spring-boot-jsontodb-master\src\main\resources\json\response.json
```

So instead of `"/json/response.json"` you should use: `json/response.json`

```
InputStream inputStream1 = TypeReference.class.getResourceAsStream("json/response.json");
```

just delete the first slash.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument "src" is null

Comment: `json - response.json` is this your file name?